# How to return multiple Menu.Items in one ternary expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to be able to return multiple menu items based on whether the user is authenticated or not. The UI Library I am using for this Ant-Design.

Attempts:

```
{
  this.props.isAuthenticated ?
    <React.Fragment>
       <Menu.Item key="1" onClick={this.props.logout}>
          Logout
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="3">
            <Link to="/">Posts</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
     </React.Fragment>
                      :
        <Menu.Item key="2">
           <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
}
```

but when I do this, it breaks my menu and shows "..." in place of the nav menu options. Also, it is heavily worth noting that this is a known issue for antdesign :
 https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/10688

Is there a work around to this or do I have to switch UI libraries? Thank you

Comment: it's hard for us to say, what might be the problem, the code you provided should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an array, instead of `React.Fragment`

```
<Menu>
  {this.props.isAuthenticated ? (
    [
      <Menu.Item key="1">
        <span>Option 1</span>
      </Menu.Item>,
      <Menu.Item key="2">
        <span>Option 2</span>
      </Menu.Item>
    ]
  ) : (
    <Menu.Item key="3">
      <span>Option 3</span>
    </Menu.Item>
  )}
</Menu>
```

Codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/2v8yo63m1r). A better solution would be to just move this logic out to a `getMenuItems` function and return the required `Menu.Item`s as an array.

Comment: this worked. Thank you very much. For some reason when I tried to add [] around the menu items, it gave me the "jsx expression must have 1 parent" error.

Comment: You probably missed the comma in between the Menu items.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and later on the same error message. Comma fixed it, thanks